# How to use Reactive FormGroup with Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using reactive form group with Angular Material design. However, I'm getting an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined

Pointing to this line of code:

```
<input formControlName="fieldName" ngDefaultControl matInput placeholder="Field Name">
<mat-error *ngIf="fieldName.invalid">
  Field name is required
</mat-error>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AddFieldComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {
      this.form = this.fb.group({
        fieldName: ['', Validators.required],
        fieldType: ['', Validators.required]
      });
    }
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<div [formGroup]="form" class="add-field">
  <div mat-dialog-content>
    <h2>Add Fields</h2>
    <mat-form-field>
      <input formControlName="fieldName" ngDefaultControl matInput placeholder="Field Name">
      <mat-error *ngIf="fieldName.invalid">
        Field name is required
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select formControlName="fieldType">
        <mat-option value="text-field">Text Field</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="radio-btn">Radio Button</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <span class="right-align-next-element"></span>
    <button class="secondary-btn" mat-button (click)="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
    <button [disabled]="fieldName.invalid" class="primary-btn" mat-button (click)="addFields()" cdkFocusInitial>Add field</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `this.invalid` instead of `fieldName.invalid` ?

Comment: How about fieldName?.invalid.

Comment: @RukshanDangalla, answer worked!!

Comment: @RahulDagli It's my pleasure I could help. Please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options you have.

**Option 1**

Wrap the element with a div or span with below check

```
*ngIf="fieldName && fieldName.invalid"
```

**Option 2**

Always use:

```
fieldName?.invalid
```

When you want to access invalid property of fieldName

Comment: This answer might have been correct in 2018, but in 2019 I can say that this answer is misleading because it only tells how to suppress the error, but not how to fix it. The problem of the author is that he accesses the property incorrectly. His code assumes that fieldName is a property on the component, but it is not, that is why it is undefined. The correct way to access the property is form.controls.fieldName. "controls" field on the FormGroup is an object containing all FormControl instances

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have a variable in typescript where you store FormControl object (example fieldName: FormControl), you cannot use `*ngIf="fieldName.invalid"` in html template, just because `fieldName` is not a variable.

I solved by getting controls from form variable (form: FormGroup) `*ngIf="form.get('fieldName')?.invalid"`. Also in the buttons in bottom `[disabled]="!form.dirty || form?.invalid"`.